# Почему SELECT возвращает NULL внутри триггера?

Tags: sql-server, select, триггер

Я создаю триггер, который уменьшает количество книг в библиотеке, когда удаляется читатель, который не вернул книги.
Читатель может не вернуть много книг, поэтому записи о возврате книг просматриваются последовательно:
`SELECT @idHistory = MIN ( ID ) FROM BookHistory WHERE ReaderID = @idColumn AND RealDate is null`
Выполняя выборку вне триггера, ожидаемо выводится ID соответствующей записи. При отработке триггера выборка возвращает NULL. С чем это может быть связано?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_1] 
   ON [dbo].[Reader] 
   FOR DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @idColumn INT
    SELECT @idColumn = MIN( ID ) FROM deleted

    WHILE @idColumn is not null
    BEGIN
        
        DECLARE @idHistory INT;
        -- В этом запросе ничего не возвращается
        SELECT @idHistory = MIN ( ID ) FROM BookHistory WHERE ReaderID = @idColumn AND RealDate is null

        WHILE @idHistory is not null
        BEGIN
            UPDATE Book SET Count = Count - 1 WHERE ID = (SELECT BookID FROM BookHistory WHERE ID = @idHistory)
            SELECT @idHistory = MIN ( ID ) FROM BookHistory WHERE ReaderID = @idColumn AND RealDate is null AND ID > @idHistory
        END

        SELECT @idColumn = MIN( ID ) FROM deleted WHERE ID > @idColumn
    END

END
```

Comment: А у вас случаем на BookHistory.ReaderID нет внешнего ключа с ON DELETE CASCADE?

Comment: Подобный цикл лучше делать через `CURSOR`, а не так как у вас

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, изначально его не было. Но так как мне нужно удалять все записи о том, что читатель брал книги, то я включил каскадное удаление всех записей при удалении читателя.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что к моменту запуска триггера записи уже каскадно удалены, поэтому запрос ничего не возвращает?

Comment: Да. «Триггер AFTER выполняется только после того, как вызывающая срабатывание триггера инструкция SQL успешно выполняется. Успешное выполнение также подразумевает завершение всех ссылочных каскадных действий и проверки ограничений, связанных с измененными или удаленными объектами.» https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, можете подсказать, а каким образом я могу получить доступ к данным, которые удаляются каскадно? Нет триггера, который бы срабатывал до удаления, а таблица deleted, как я понимаю, содержит только удалённые записи из главной таблицы.

Comment: Вариант 1: Триггер INSTEAD OF DELETE. Срабатывает до, точнее вместо удаления. Выполнить все предполагаемые действия внутри триггера, и удалить строки deleted из таблицы явно. Вариант 2: Триггер после удаления на BookHistory. Если удаляемая строка не содержит даты возврата, то уменьшить счётчик.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно лучше убрать каскадное удаление и триггер, сделать вычисляемый столбец IsDeleted в таблице BookHistory со следующей логикой: если даты возврата нет, а с момента выдачи прошло N дней(месяцев, лет), то 1 иначе 0.

*Так у тебя и история книг сохранится, и неожиданности с каскадным удалением уйдут, и недостатки триггера исчезнут вместе с ним.*